# How to Unit Test class annotated with @AndroidEntryPoint

Tags: android, unit-testing, dagger-hilt

I'm attempting to write a test case for a BroadcastReceiver class in my Android application that is annotated with **@AndroidEntryPoint** for Dagger-Hilt integration. However, I'm encountering an exception during the test execution. Below are the relevant code snippets for the class, the test class, and the details of the exception:

Here is the class:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyBroadcast : BroadcastReceiver() {

  @Inject
  lateinit var myRepository: MyRepository

  override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
      myRepository.updateData()
  }

}
```

Here is the test class:

```
class MyBroadCastTest {
private lateinit var myBroadcast: MyBroadcast

@RelaxedMockK
lateinit var mockMyRepository: MyRepository

@Before
fun setUp() {
    MockKAnnotations.init(this)
    myBroadcast = MyBroadcast()
    myBroadcast.myRepository = this.mockMyRepository
}

@Test
fun shouldUpdateDataOnReceivingBroadcast() {
    val mockContext = mockk<Context>(relaxed = true)
    val mockIntent = mockk<Intent>(relaxed = true)
    myBroadcast.onReceive(mockContext, mockIntent)

    verify { mockMyRepository.updateData() }
}

@After
fun tearDown() {
    unmockkAll()
}

}
```

The exception:

```
com.example.app.broadcast.MyBroadcastTest > shouldUpdateDataOnReceivingBroadcast FAILED
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find an Application in the given context: Context(child of mockContext#1#10)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.Contexts.getApplication(Contexts.java:42)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.BroadcastReceiverComponentManager.generatedComponent(BroadcastReceiverComponentManager.java:33)
at com.example.app..broadcast.Hilt_MyBroadcast.inject(Hilt_MyBroadcast.java:34)
at com.example.app..broadcast.Hilt_MyBroadcast.onReceive(Hilt_MyBroadcast.java:27)
at com.example.app..broadcast.MyBroadcast.onReceive(MyBroadcast.kt)
at com.example.app..broadcast.MyBroadcastTest.shouldFetchFirebaseTokenOnReceivingBroadcast(MyBroadcastTest.kt:62)
```

I've been working on resolving the issue by referring to the Hilt documentation, but progress has been slower than expected. Could you please provide guidance or assistance on how to address this situation more effectively?

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyBroadcast` class doesn't actually extend `BroadcastReceiver` directly, it extends `Hilt_MyBroadcast` (generated by Hilt) and that class extends `BroadcastReceiver`. Hilt does this byte-code transformation and puts its own class in between. It's not that obvious in the IDE, but you can search and find this class after you made a build.

Inside of the `Hilt_MyBroadcast` class Hilt tries to get applicationContext from the `Context` you give in the test. However that fails because you give a mocked Context with almost no configuration. When you mock like this `mockk<Context>(relaxed = true)` then MockK returns default values from functions, for example if a function returns Int, mockk just returns 0. In this case `Context#applicationContext` returns a null value.

My suggestions:

1. [Do not mock what you don't own.](https://testing.googleblog.com/2020/07/testing-on-toilet-dont-mock-types-you.html) `Context` is *not* a class developed by you and therefore you should *not* mock it. Because `Context` has many behaviors that could be easily missed while writing a mock, such as returning a value from `Context#applicationContext`.
2. If you want to run this test as a unit test (on a non-Android JVM such as on your computer instead of an Android device or emulator) then you might want to check [Robolectric](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric). Robolectric has 'shadows' for Android classes like `Context` that allows you to test them on a non-Android JVM. You can [register](https://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.8/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowApplication.html#registerReceiver-android.content.BroadcastReceiver-android.content.IntentFilter-java.lang.String-android.os.Handler-) your receiver in the test then [send a broadcast](https://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.8/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowApplication.html#sendBroadcast-android.content.Intent-).
3. If you have `kaptTest(hilt)` (or `kspTest(hilt)`) in your build.gradle file then Hilt will run its compiler in the test source-set as well. This is the reason you see `Hilt_MyBroadcast` in the stacktrace. I would run Hilt in the test source-sets only if I'm actually using Hilt to inject dependencies, because it's time consuming to run it unnecessarily and have a negative build time impact. If you don't use Hilt to inject dependencies, then you can remove `kaptTest(hilt)` from your module. If you want to use Hilt to inject dependencies: keep `kaptTest(hilt)` in your module and you would still need to add Robolectric and register your BroadcastReceiver because `Context` won't be available outside of an Android device or emulator. Robolectric makes Android APIs available on non-Android JVMs. Once you have Hilt in test dependencies, if you are testing `AndroidEntryPoint` then you ask Android to create an instance (in this case by registering and sending a broadcast). As completeness of this post, for non-AndroidEntryPoint dependencies: you can create `EntryPoint` interface with a function that returns an instance of the class you are testing, then in the test use `EntryPoint` API to get an instance of the tested class. Use `TestIntallIn` or new Dagger modules in test source-set if you want to bind or replace dependencies for tests.
4. If you want to run this test not as a unit test but as an instrumented test (on an Android JVM such as a device or an emulator) then you don't need Robolectric. If you want to use Hilt in the instrumented tests then you will need to add `kaptAndroidTest(hilt)` instead of `kaptTest(hilt)`.

I know it's a bit tricky to set it up but I hope this post helps. Let me know if you have further questions and good luck!